# Remove space only from the beginning of the paragraph while reading file in PHP

Tags: php, file-handling, removing-whitespace

Hello friends i am reading a folder in which i have many text files in PHP and i need to remove all the spaces from the starting of each paragraph in text file. But when i am reading file and tried to remove space its not working like i tried **TRIM** function **LTRIM** and also tried REGEX **"/\s+$/"** but all are not working. But when i am using REGEX this **"/\s+/"** instead of **"/\s+$/"** its removing all the spaces. I need only remove space from the beginning of paragraph any help please...Below is my code that i am trying..

```
if ($dh = opendir($folder_path)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
        $path_parts = pathinfo($file);
        if ($path_parts['extension'] === 'txt' && $file1 = fopen($folder_path . '/' . $file, "r")) {
            $cleanStr ="";
            while(!feof($file1)) {
                $line = trim(fgets($file1));
                if ( trim($line)!="" ){
                    $str = preg_replace("/\s+$/", " ", ltrim($line));
                    echo $str;die;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo "Process finished..." . PHP_EOL;
    closedir($dh);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by " all not working " ? return a null string or return the string with the spaces?

Comment: No, before and after string are same.

Comment: your code is working with me correctly!

Comment: Did you try trim or ltrim? It's a big difference.

Comment: See the comments to the answers also. Do you use css or any other styling?

Comment: @hassan - No hassan i tried this but its not working.. I am using command prompt to run this code and this is my text file and it is saved with this name of  "audioid_0B09868D0B0AB4337AA9-calldate_20170606.wav".txt ..  See this --  https://prnt.sc/hxxakr

Comment: No @Andreas i am not..and i tried both trim and ltrim.

Answer (score 1):

Use `/^\s+/` to match spaces at the start of the paragraph. E.g.

```
$str = preg_replace("/^\s+/", "", $line);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this but its not working...I am using fgets($file1) for reading file may be its including extra white space in beginning of each paragraph

Comment: Are you sure you're not just wanting to remove `$line = trim(fgets($file1));`? This will destroy any space around the line when you first read it from the file, so all other trimming is useless.

Comment: If you're getting EXTRA whitespace at the start of each line when it's `echo`ed in PHP, it's probably not coming from this bit of the code. Maybe you have extra whitespace in your HTML before this block of PHP code?

Comment: Something BEFORE the code that's reading the text file (and writing the trimmed contents) is adding the extra whitespace...  we can't see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this a couple of years ago for a similar task - seemed to work ok, perhaps it might be of use - though if you do not wish to edit the file rather than use `file_put_contents` simply `echo implode(PHP_EOL, $content );`

```
<?php
    /* find all files in chosen folder */
    $col=glob( $folder_path . '\*.*' );

    /* filter only text files for processing */
    $col=preg_grep( '@(\.txt$)@i', $col );

    /* Proceed if there are text files only */
    if( !empty( $col ) ){

        /* iterate through collection */
        foreach( $col as $index => $filepath ){

            /* read file contents into an array */
            $lines=file( $filepath );

            /* store altered lines in temp array */
            $content=array();

            /* trim the start of each line & store into temp array */
            foreach( $lines as $line )if( !empty( $line ) )$content[]=ltrim( $line );

            /* write content back to file */
            file_put_contents( $filepath, implode( PHP_EOL, $data ) );
        }
        echo "finito!";
    }
?>
```

---

The test script used a single text file called `lorem.txt` with the following contents.

```
                                                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque suscipit lacus massa, in malesuada quam consectetur at. Proin fermentum augue vel purus pellentesque placerat. Nunc tincidunt mi ac est varius, id euismod est auctor. Mauris facilisis luctus justo tristique consectetur. Vestibulum tempus lacinia blandit. Praesent dui metus, aliquet ut velit vitae, suscipit volutpat tortor. Nunc dictum nunc sed nisi bibendum dictum id vitae lorem. Donec viverra eget odio in hendrerit. Mauris iaculis at eros at scelerisque. Suspendisse a consequat erat, in fringilla diam. Fusce vitae hendrerit lacus. Ut sed purus vel metus semper sagittis. Ut fermentum magna quis tempus scelerisque.

    Phasellus quis rhoncus sapien. Nulla bibendum sagittis metus. Praesent elementum ex augue, a ullamcorper velit consectetur in. Maecenas mollis neque eu massa feugiat rutrum. Sed eu aliquam nulla. Sed sit amet egestas eros. Donec commodo leo in pellentesque efficitur. Cras ornare dui iaculis ultricies lobortis. Vivamus vel tellus maximus, sodales odio quis, ultrices metus.

       Nullam vitae rhoncus justo, a congue turpis. Nulla facilisi. Nulla faucibus massa et arcu molestie dignissim. Maecenas aliquet posuere eros sit amet vehicula. Praesent quis arcu eros. Quisque vitae dictum orci. Integer quis mollis felis.

    Morbi vitae risus fringilla, ornare ipsum ac, tincidunt metus. Ut ac eros placerat, auctor metus non, sollicitudin metus. Aenean malesuada gravida dolor, sit amet blandit lacus dignissim at. In egestas nibh felis, pulvinar laoreet eros rhoncus quis. Donec pulvinar condimentum ex, quis faucibus massa placerat sed. Fusce in mattis sem, sed rutrum nibh. Donec vitae risus urna. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas vitae neque tempus, malesuada dolor et, rhoncus orci.

Duis quis augue vitae sapien cursus suscipit. Nulla rutrum eget diam in feugiat. Vestibulum posuere dapibus nisl at laoreet. Donec ante arcu, euismod et finibus ut, malesuada sed augue. Nunc porttitor leo ex, eget luctus augue sollicitudin non. Proin nec cursus ipsum. Nulla mi enim, finibus a felis vitae, pharetra tempor tortor. Proin a arcu lectus.
```

Most of the above lines have either spaces or tabs at the beginning

```
<?php

    $folder_path='c:/wwwroot/content/stack';
    $trim='rtrim';


    /* find all files in chosen folder */
    $col=glob( $folder_path . '\*.*' );

    /* filter only text files for processing */
    $col=preg_grep( '@(\.txt$)@i', $col );

    /* Proceed if there are text files only */
    if( !empty( $col ) && count( $col ) > 0 ){

        /* iterate through collection */
        foreach( $col as $index => $filepath ){

            /* read file contents into an array */
            $lines=file( $filepath );

            /* store altered lines in temp array */
            $content=array();

            /* trim the start of each line & store into temp array */
            foreach( $lines as $line )if( !empty( $line ) ){
                $content[]=$trim( $line );
            }

            /* write content back to file */
            #file_put_contents( $filepath, implode( PHP_EOL, $data ) );
            echo "<pre>" . implode( PHP_EOL, $content ) . "</pre>";
        }
        printf( "finito! %d files processed",count( $col ) );
    } else {
        echo "nothing to process";
    }
?>
```

Simply by changing the variable `$trim` from `rtrim` to `ltrim` the output is as expected

---

The following modifies the original file ( don't know if that is an issue ) and was run from the cmdline-all spaces from beginning of lines are removed.

```
<?php

    $folder_path='c:/wwwroot/content/stack';



    /* find all files in chosen folder */
    $col=glob( $folder_path . '\*.*' );

    /* filter only text files for processing */
    $col=preg_grep( '@(\.txt$)@i', $col );

    /* Proceed if there are text files only */
    if( !empty( $col ) && count( $col ) > 0 ){

        /* iterate through collection */
        foreach( $col as $index => $filepath ){

            /* read file contents into an array */
            $lines=file( $filepath );

            /* store altered lines in temp array */
            $content=array();

            /* trim the start of each line & store into temp array */
            foreach( $lines as $line )if( !empty( $line ) ) $content[]=ltrim( $line );


            /* output file contents */
            file_put_contents( $filepath, implode( PHP_EOL, $content ) );
            echo file_get_contents( $filepath ) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
        }
        printf( "finito! %d files processed",count( $col ) );
    } else {
        echo "nothing to process";
    }
?>
```

Comment: is there anything unusual about the contents of these files? I just ran this as a test and it stripped leading spaces and tabs fine

Comment: No nothing unusual. It have only a single line string .. see this https://prnt.sc/hxxakr

Comment: the screenshot is of a `.wav` file is it not?

Comment: No mate its a txt file which is saved with the name of "audioid_0B09868D0B0AB4337AA9-calldate_20170606.wav".txt

Comment: Please reply any one... i am still waiting?

Comment: Well - I have tried the code and in each and every occasion it worked - I even created a duplicate of the file you indicated with a screenshot, named it the same and ran the script.

Comment: Could you try this code by running command prompt and don't forgot to add space in the beginning of the first paragraph.

Comment: See this is my text file .. http://prntscr.com/hxy0bc

and this is my output ---http://prntscr.com/hxy144

Comment: Yes that's what i was saying. Can you suggest me any solution?